# Convert bitmap to postscript

Tags: c#, bitmap, postscript

I am looking to convert a System.Drawing.Bitmap object to a format which postscript will be able to render.

The format I am trying to use is where you specify the width, height, bits per pixel and a transformaiton matrix. Is there any easy way I can get the pixel from a bitmap image?

The current pixel depth is set to 1 bit per pixel.

The output I would be looking for would be something like this:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ff000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef0000ffffffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ce00ffffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00cece00ffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00cecece00ffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00cececece00ffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00000000000000ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efef000000ef000000ef000000ef0000ef0000efefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efef000000ef00000000ef00000000ef000000efefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efef0000ef00000000000000ef000000ef0000efefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Managed to get the above working with the following:

```
 for (int iii = 0; iii < bitmap.Height*bitmap.Width; iii++)
        {
            int row = iii/bitmap.Width;
            int col = iii%bitmap.Width;
            Color pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(col, row);

            sb.Append(pixel.R.ToString("X2") + pixel.G.ToString("X2") + pixel.B.ToString("X2"));

            if (iii > 0 && iii%bitmap.Width == 0)
            {
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
        }
```

However it appears that I cannot draw more than 1 image per page. If after teh image i inser showpage, the additional content is shown on the next page. But without show page, none is added.

Is there any sort of close that I need to put in after the image, at the moment it ends with

`false 3 colorimage`

I think I may have solved this issue aswell, if I do a `gsave` before any of the image drawing commands and then a `grestore` after, everything seems okay. I haev no idea if this is the preferred method though.

Comment: From the info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) I'm only seeing 2 ways to access the data, `.GetPixel()` and `.ISerializable.GetObjectData()`, then convert to hex.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to be asking, "is there way to get the pixel from the image", then you show C# code to just that. So what do you really want to know?